# /Gh and /GH causing my application not to start

Tags: windows, visual-c++, 64-bit

I have a x64 Visual C++ application that I need to have _penter and _pexit hooks for. I have written the asm file and added it to the application and it calls a function I need from my application and it compiles fine. But I saw that the _penter and _exit functions are not called. I added /GH and /Gh options to my application but after I added that it does not start but just quits. I have no log file generated from my application and the Windows' "Event Viewer" also does not show any error. Where else can I look for errors? Could I have missed something obvious?

Comment: That's pretty good evidence that your penter/exit functions are in fact being called.  That penter caused your main() function to misbehave isn't unusual of course.  We can't see it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I figured out that it was being called, but the application very soon crashing due to stack overflow! I am trying to figure out why that would be.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out! https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e3eb492-69ac-49a2-86ad-9b16a391996e/penter-cause-stack-overflow?forum=vclanguage It becomes a recursive call and so a stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured it out!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e3eb492-69ac-49a2-86ad-9b16a391996e/penter-cause-stack-overflow?forum=vclanguage

It becomes a recursive call and so a stackoverflow.

Thanks!